# Change the time part of a date with a timespan value

Tags: vb.net, date, time, timespan

If I have a `DateTime` variable with this value `2020/01/01 20:59:54` and a `TimeSpan` variable with this value `16:35:00`. How can I change the time part of my date variable with the value of the `TimeSpan` variable to have a result like this `2020/01/01 16:35:00`?

Comment: I changed your date formats to use the ISO standard format as SO is an international site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Parse("2020/01/01 20:59:54")
Dim ts = TimeSpan.Parse("16:35:00")

dt = dt.Date.Add(ts)
```

Or, even more simply:

```
dt = dt.Date + ts
```

Comment: It's worth noting that dates and times also support standard arithmetic operators since about 2008 or 2010: `dt = dt.Date + ts`.